# How to customize the invariant of a template AVL tree?

Tags: c++, c++17, avl-tree

I am developing a generic AVL tree and would like to use T's < and > operators by 
default but also have the option of substituting custom ones so I can have greater control over the invariant and free T from the need to fit inside my box.

I'm not very familiar with function pointers / objects in C++, where should I be looking? std::bind()? lambdas?

```
template <typename T>
class avl_tree
{
   private:

   std::shared_ptr<avl_node<T>> root_ {nullptr};

   // > function object? uses T's > by default
   // < function object? uses T's < by default

   public: 

   avl_tree() = default;

   // avl_tree(?, ?) constructor accepting overloads
   //                for the < and > operators
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You should mimic [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set). Take a comparator as template argument:

```
template <typename T, class Compare = std::less<Key>>
class avl_tree
{
private:
    Compare comp;

public:
    avl_tree() = default;
    avl_tree(Compare comp) : comp{comp} {}
}
```

And compare with

```
comp(a, b); // instead of (a < b)
comp(b, a); // instead of (b < a)
```

Comment: Thank you I'll look into it

Answer (score 0):

I found this resource enlightening, for anyone else unfamiliar with C++'s function object conventions

https://www.quantstart.com/articles/Function-Objects-Functors-in-C-Part-1